# Logging of unit test result using AspectJ

Tags: junit, aop

I'm trying to log my test suite results using AspectJ. I'd like to 'inject' the results identification code after each @Test method in my code, so created an aspect with the following method:

```
  @After("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.junit.Test)")
  public void afterTestMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
      //identify test result
  }
```

However, can't find how to retrieve the test method result (passed/failed/skipped).
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that? What is wrong with the test reports generated by Maven, Gradle, JUnit itself or your IDE? Why re-invent the wheel? I like to understand before deciding if it makes any sense to write an answer.

Comment: I'd like to report the results to an external monitoring system using its API. Hence, I have to get the status of each test case and make an API call with the test ID & the test result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A) JUnit run listener

I am assuming that you build your project with something like Maven or Gradle and will show you a Maven example for a JUnit 4 [RunListener](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html):

In module `test-tools` you would add

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13</version>
  <!--
    We build something with the JUnit API, not just run a test,
    so scope 'test' is not enough here
  -->
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your POM and then have something like this in `src/main/java/...`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.testing;

import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

public class ResultPrintingRunListener extends RunListener {
  @Override
  public void testRunStarted(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[RunStarted] description = " + description);
  }

  @Override
  public void testRunFinished(Result result) {
    System.out.println("[RunFinished] result = " + result);
    System.out.println("  run count = " + result.getRunCount());
    System.out.println("  failure count = " + result.getFailureCount());
    System.out.println("  assumption failure count = " + result.getAssumptionFailureCount());
    System.out.println("  ignored count = " + result.getIgnoreCount());
    System.out.println("  run time (ms) = " + result.getRunTime());
  }

  @Override
  public void testSuiteStarted(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[SuiteStarted] description = " + description);
  }

  @Override
  public void testSuiteFinished(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[SuiteFinished] description = " + description);
  }

  @Override
  public void testStarted(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[Started] description = " + description);
  }

  @Override
  public void testFinished(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[Finished] description = " + description);
  }

  @Override
  public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
    System.out.println("[Failure] failure = " + failure);
  }

  @Override
  public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {
    System.out.println("[AssumptionFailure] failure = " + failure);
  }

  @Override
  public void testIgnored(Description description) {
    System.out.println("[Ignored] description = " + description);
  }
}
```

Instead of logging you would put your API calls in there at the appropriate places.

In your application test module you would add the `test-tools` module as a dependency and then configure your Maven Surefire/Failsafe plugins like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>de.scrum_master.testing.ResultPrintingRunListener</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If then you run a test like this in Maven, ...

```java
package de.scrum_master.agent.aspect;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void one() {
    Assert.assertEquals("xander", "Alexander".substring(3));
  }

  @Test
  public void two() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Alex", "Alexander".substring(3));
  }

  @Test
  public void three() {
    Assert.assertEquals(11, 1 / 0);
  }

  @Test
  @Ignore
  public void four() {
    Assert.assertNull(null);
  }
}
```

... Maven prints:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[RunStarted] description = null
[INFO] Running de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest
[SuiteStarted] description = de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest
[Started] description = one(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Finished] description = one(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Started] description = two(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Failure] failure = two(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest): expected:<[Alex]> but was:<[xander]>
[Finished] description = two(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Ignored] description = four(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Started] description = three(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[Failure] failure = three(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest): / by zero
[Finished] description = three(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[SuiteFinished] description = de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.11 s <<< FAILURE! - in de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest
[ERROR] de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest.two  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Alex]> but was:<[xander]>
    at de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest.two(MyTest.java:31)

[ERROR] de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest.three  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest.three(MyTest.java:36)

[RunFinished] result = org.junit.runner.Result@79be0360
  run count = 3
  failure count = 2
  assumption failure count = 0
  ignored count = 1
  run time (ms) = 0
```

#### JUnit test watcher rule

If you prefer something which is independent of a specific JUnit runner right inside your tests, create a base class like this using JUnit [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html):

```java
package de.scrum_master.agent.aspect;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class TestBase {
  @Rule(order = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
  public TestWatcher testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      System.out.println("[TestWatcher failed] description = " + description +", e = " + e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
      System.out.println("[TestWatcher succeeded] description = " + description);
    }
  };
}
```

Then make all your test classes `extends TestBase` directly or indirectly. If you run the test, e.g. from an IDE, you see (shortened output, only test watcher log):

```
[TestWatcher succeeded] description = one(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest)
[TestWatcher failed] description = two(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest), e = org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Alex]> but was:<[xander]>
[TestWatcher failed] description = three(de.scrum_master.agent.aspect.MyTest), e = java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

You see, there are fewer events in the test watcher, e.g. ignored tests are not reported.

As much as I love AspectJ (which is how I found this question), I think you should try configuring JUnit appropriately first and will probably be happy with it. If for whatever reason - please explain, if so - you still insist in an AOP solution, please let me know.

---

#### (C) Intercept JUnit tests directly

Because you insisted:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspectj;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class TestResultInterceptor {
  @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.junit.Test)", returning = "result")
  public void allMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> PASSED");
  }

  @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.junit.Test)", throwing = "throwable")
  public void allMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable throwable) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> FAILED: " + throwable);
  }
}
```

When running the JUnit test above in my IDE, the console log is:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.testing.MyTest.one()) -> PASSED
execution(void de.scrum_master.testing.MyTest.two()) -> FAILED: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Alex]> but was:<[xander]>
execution(void de.scrum_master.testing.MyTest.three()) -> FAILED: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. However I have to insist on AOP solution. I need to develop this extension for some aspect in the corporation I work for. From reasons of code-reuse and code-extensibility, the logic that I described must be a part of an aspect which is responsible for test monitoring end-to-end.

Comment: Sorry, your argument does not make any sense. Just because there is an existing aspect  calling this API, it does not mean that for the sake of expanding the functionality to testing (which is a new way of using the aspect, obviously because otherwise it would be working already) you have to use an aspect again. A small test listener calling the same API **is** code re-use. It would be a design flaw to have one "God class" (or "God aspect", for that matter) doing everything.

Comment: Please note that the test runner is usually loosely coupled to the JVM running the tests, running in another process. I.e. the aspect running in process with the test does not even see any classes of the test framework you could hook into. If you want to intercept test results, you need to start the test engine with an aspect weaving agent on its own command line, you don't weave into your tests themselves. You are trying to target the wrong thing! But if you hook into the test engine, you can more easily just write an extension for it, it is cleaner and less invasive.

Comment: This is a wonderful example for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): You are not focusing on **what** you want to achieve but obsessing about **how** you want to achieve it technically, which makes you blind for better solutions. Of course you can try to hammer nails into the wall with a spade or an axe, but probably you will be more efficient and hurt yourself less using the right tool: a hammer.

Comment: _"The logic that I described must be a part of an aspect which is responsible for test monitoring end-to-end."_ So this aspect exists already? Why is it not working? And if it does not exist yet, why are you insisting it has to be an aspect? I cannot help but notice that you are contradicting yourself. Anyway, please update your question explaining exactly how your aspect and the rest of the tool chain work technically, then I can try to help with the aspect part. And does the solution only have to work in the back-end or also when running tests from an IDE? I need much more information!

Comment: Please note my update with a simple AspectJ solution because you insisted... But with this solution you miss ignored tests, just like with the test watcher rule. If you want all the details, you do need the run listener.